# Rails 2.3.12: Limiting routes to specific HTTP verbs

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a status controller for reporting how my application is functioning.  It has two basic actions:

1. How do things look right now?
2. Poke all the pieces to update their status, and then process as #1.

The paths are `status` and `status/ping` respectively.

I want to restrict these to **only** `GET` for `status` and **only** `POST` for `status/ping`.  The current route structure looks like this:

```
map.connect('status',      :controller => 'status', :action => 'index')
map.connect('status/ping', :controller => 'status', :action => 'ping')
```

I've tried various combinations of `:via` and `:only` with no success.

How can I impose verb restrictions on these paths?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `:only` option is for the Restful routes. According to the [2.3.8 docs](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Routing), what you're looking for is the following.

```
map.connect('status', :controller => 'status', :action => 'index', :conditions => { :method => :get })
map.connect('status/ping', :controller => 'status', :action => 'ping', :conditions => { :method => :post })
```

Comment: Wow.  That works.  I was **sure** I tried that one..  Thanks!